# Compiling a program for Windows XP x86

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build, x86

I wrote a windows forms application using VS2012 on windows 8 computer (x64) and I want it to run on Windows XP x86. When I try to run the program I get error "... is not a valid windows 32 application."
How can i fix it?

Comment: build the program for x86 configuration

Answer (score 2):

- Right Click Project Name on solution Explorer.
- Select Properties
- Select Build Tab
- Select x86 option for Platform target DropDownList
- Save and build the project

Also make sure that you target the .Net Framework Version same as the version present in Testing machine.

If you are building C++ project then try this:

> General -> Platform Toolset -> Visual Studio 2012 -> Windows XP
>   (v110_xp)

Comment: What if it is a c# project?

Answer (score 2):

Its better that you choose the target as Any CPU .

The compiler shall decide how to invoke the program ( x86 or x64 ) when you choose the Any CPU option , also choose the Any CPU platform.

[image]

Comment: How so? I never had trouble with this.

Comment: @AthomSfere native dependencies with no 64bit equivalent. It's going to work in this case obviously (OP already has it running as x64), but that's more of the exception rather than the rule. Even so, it's a lot like writing two programs at once, where the code must be the same, and you have to do your best to make the semantics equivalent in both scenario's. It's only easy when you stay within the managed part.

Comment: @harold Yes, I see what you meant now. Yes, if you stay in C# and .NET no issues, but as soon as you leave those very safe frameworks you certainly need to be more explicit and careful with everything

Answer (score 1):

Maybe far away guess with given that less information.

You should change Compile Target to x86 from

```
Project->Application Properties->Compile 

Set Target CPU to x86
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may be experiencing issues related to the Windows XP Targeting for C++ in Visual Studio 2012. Support for Windows XP with C++ targets was added in Visual Studio 2012 Update 1, but must still be explicitly selected in your project properties.

[Windows XP Targeting with C++ in Visual Studio 2012](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/10/08/10357555.aspx)

There is a great deal of additional information at the above link, but the specific setting you are looking for in the C++ project properties is General → Platform Toolset → **Visual Studio 2012 - Windows XP (v110_xp)**

Comment: +1 afaik this is the core solution to the problem (without this it definitely will not work, no matter if you pick x86 or AnyCPU), makes me wonder why no one upvoted this earlier?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue except the project is in c# not c++, I just installed the update, will this change apply to my project as well?

Comment: No, this only applies to C++. The .NET Framework version you target determines compatibility with Windows XP. .NET 4.0 works with XP SP3, .NET 3.5 works with XP SP2, and .NET 2.0 works with any version of Windows XP. .NET 4.5 requires Windows Vista or later.